# inference model predicts same words repeatedly in encoder-decoder

Tags: lstm, summarization, encoder-decoder

I'm training encoder-decoder with LSTM, for generating abstractive review summaries on Amazon Kindle dataset. For every input the output summaries are slightly different but they generate a couple of words repeatedly.

I have tried a random sampling of the softmax probabilities at each decoder timestep. Thus results are different for every input but not relating to the input text.
Plotting histogram of softmax probabilities at every time step shows similar distribution, though numbers are slightly different. 
I have tried reducing the learning rate

input : i loved the book very well written will read again nice read

output : SOS cannot cannot stress stress stress stress tear tear tear crook